# Swift 4 contains method doesn't work truly for short words like "as"

Tags: swift, string, substring

I use contains method to find if a string has same word in it. But this code print "hello" :

```
var a = "was founded"
if a.range(of: "as") != nil
{
    print("hello")
}else {

    print("noooo")
}
```

How can I find if a string contains same word in it. I can't make this with foreach loop because sometimesi search for collocations like : "the fact that"

Comment: FYI - you are not using `contains`, you are using `range(of:)`. But they, by default, do simple substring searches, not word searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression to make sure the word you're looking for has word boundaries on both sides (instead of other letters). Use:

```
if a.range(of: "\\bas\\b", options: [.regularExpression], range: (a.startIndex..<a.endIndex), locale: nil) != nil {
```

The regular expression keyword `\\b` is to match a word boundary.